# Accidentally ended שמע קולנו with העונה בעת צרה

Tags: fast-days, mistakes

What should you do if, on a fast day, you said Aneinu in Shema Koleinu and then accidentally continued with the conclusion for Aneinu, ברוך אתה ה' העונה בעת צרה, instead of finishing with כי אתה שומע?

If you remember within 3 seconds, should you correct it to שומע תפלה, even though there's no מעין חתימה?  If you remember later, should you go back to Shema Koleinu?  If you finished Shemoneh Esrei, should you start over?

Comment: No מעין חתימה? I'm not so sure. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17597/759

Comment: @DoubleAA every nusach you have there has some kind of אתה שומע.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean I'm convinced. So much confusion about it indicates there's potentially some flexibility. Not that I'm conceding מעין חתימה is necessary after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

> If you remember within 3 seconds, should you correct it to שומע תפלה,
>   even though there's no מעין חתימה?

You should correct it according to the Shevet Halevi [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1418&st=&pgnum=121) and Rivivos Ephraim [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=301&hilite=)

> If you remember later, should you go back to Shema Koleinu?

The sefer Ishei Yisroel - halacha 10 - writes that you should go back to Shema Koleinu, however in footnote 36 he quotes those that disagree with this.

> If you finished Shemoneh Esrei, should you start over?

According to The Ishei Yisroel you should repeat Shemoneh Esrei, other disagree see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=173&pgnum=52) and Yabia Omer 7/13 who writes that one should repeat it with a condition that if it's not needed it should be a תפלת נדבה - a donated Shemoneh Esrei.

[image: copy of sefer ishei yisroel]

Comment: If the Chatimot are interchangeable, then why does the Chazzan say the same blessing twice?